# Why are we sending the POST data as JSON in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to send data into controller. So I have to use ajax call to send it.

```
$.ajax({
       url: self.options.link,
       data: {product_id: product, form_key: formKey, email: emailId, mobile: mobNo}
});
```

Why and when we use the data:JSON.stringify({}); and data:{} for sending post data via ajax.

```
$.ajax({
       url: self.options.link,
       data: JSON.stringify({product_id: product, form_key: formKey, email: emailId, mobile: mobNo})
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common use of JSON is to exchange data to/from a web server.

When sending data to a web server, the data has to be a string.

Convert a JavaScript object into a string with `JSON.stringify()`.

source: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp

`data: JSON.stringify()` serializes a JS object into a JSON string, on the other hand, it’s only actually JSON when it’s used in a string context.

`data:{}` here you sending the json object directly not the string.

Please also check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981255/why-is-it-necessary-to-call-json-stringify-when-submitting-object-data-to-server

Comment: In which place is suitable for sending data with JSON.stringify() and without JSON.stringify().

Comment: I have updated my asnwer, let me know if any further query